# How does base-emitter voltage affect the current gain of a transistor?

Tags: electric-current, semiconductor-physics, voltage, electronics, electrical-engineering

I'm doing a Physics project related to transistor operation. My data shows that as the base-emitter voltage drop increases, the current gain of the transistor rises  and eventually plateaus at a saturation point. How can I explain the theory behind this trend?

Comment: Would [electronics.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: If you reach the saturation behavior of the BJT, the gain will drop dramatically, not just plateau. Sharing (a graph of) your data would likely make the question more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The base-emitter junction has most characteristics of a diode in a sense that the emitter current increases exponentially with the base-emitter voltage. The big difference is that, in the transistor, the lion's share of the emitter current is redirected to the collector, as long as the voltage on the collector (say, relative to the emitter) is reasonably high.

In a typical transistor circuit with a common emitter, there is a load, say, a resistor ($R_L$ on the diagram below), in the collector circuit.

[image]

As the base-emitter voltage, $V_{BE}$, increases and, following it, the emitter current and, therefore, the collector current increases, the voltage drop on the load resistor increases as well.

Since the total voltage of a battery is shared between the emitter-collector voltage and the load voltage ($V_{CC}=V_{CE}+V_{R_L}$), an increase of the voltage drop on the load leads to a decrease of the voltage on the collector and, at some point, it becomes too low to support the redirection of the electrons coming from the emitter to the base, after which the collector current will plateau.

If we kept maintaining a reasonably high voltage on the collector, the collector current would continue growing with the base-emitter voltage, exponentially, until the transistor overheated and melted.